# jQuery - change the background color for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Now I have 6 squares in the html file

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="square"> </div>
    <div class="square"> </div>
    <div class="square"> </div>
    <div class="square"> </div>
    <div class="square"> </div>
    <div class="square"> </div>
</div>
```

And I have a list of color as below:

```
var color = [
"rgb(255, 0, 0)",
"rgb(255, 255, 0)",
"rgb(0, 255, 0)",
"rgb(0, 255, 255)",
"rgb(0, 0, 255)",
"rgb(255, 0, 255)"
]
```

I would like to use jQuery to assign the colors to the squares i.e The "rgb(255, 0, 0)" for square 1, "rgb(255, 255, 0)" for square 2 etc.

First I tested the connection of the js and the HTML and it works. Then I tried a several version of jquery. The first version that I tried is

```
for (var i = 0; i<=color.length; i++) {
    $(".square").function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", color[i]);
    };
}
```

It returns no response. 
Then I tried the second version, which is with each function in the jquery and it is:

```
for (var i = 0; i<=color.length; i++) {
    $(".square").each(function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", color[i]);
    });
}
```

And the strange things happens: The the default color for all the square is purple, and now it changes to light-purple...

So, these are are my questions:

1. As I know, jquery works like the DOM querySelectorAll() in JS. And by using $(this), it carries an implicit loop here. How can I also add the color which may incur another loop? Or how to make it works?
2. What's wrong with my code and/or logic? That's would be important for me to know as a beginner or jquery...

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't loop through colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery's [`each()` mehtods](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) built in function parameters, e.g. here set `idx` to the index and `el` the element.

```
$(".square").each(function(idx, el) {
    $(el).css("background-color", color[idx]);
});
```

---

Do note, `.each()` is jQuery's way of doing a `for...loop`, and in this case you don't need both, I here used `.each()`'s built in index to get the color array's values.

You can also use `$(this)` instead of `$(el)`, I just wanted to show the built-in options.

Comment: It works and thanks! But does it mean that, inside the each function there is an implicit loop and what I have to do is just adding an parameter and assign to array elements/object element to loop it through?

Comment: @PakHangLeung The method `.each` represents the loop, and the `function` parameters `(idx, el)` will in this case be the element `el` and its array index `idx`, which can be used to pick up the color array's values.

Comment: @PakHangLeung I also  added a link to its docs, for more reading if you need to.

Comment: No. Actually I use your answer and it works. Now already added back and thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Just loop html elements or array elements and use that index to get element from other part. You don't need nested loop but you need to add some text to html to see backgrounds.

```js
var color = ["rgb(255, 0, 0)","rgb(255, 255, 0)","rgb(0, 255, 0)","rgb(0, 255, 255)","rgb(0, 0, 255)","rgb(255, 0, 255)"]

$("#container .square").each(function(i) {
  $(this).css('background', color[i])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="square">Text</div>
  <div class="square">Text</div>
  <div class="square">Text</div>
  <div class="square">Text</div>
  <div class="square">Text</div>
  <div class="square">Text</div>
</div>
```

You can also do the same with loop on array and then get html element with the same index.

```js
var color = ["rgb(255, 0, 0)","rgb(255, 255, 0)","rgb(0, 255, 0)","rgb(0, 255, 255)","rgb(0, 0, 255)","rgb(255, 0, 255)"]
color.forEach((c, i) => $(`.square:eq(${i})`).css('background', c))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="square">Text</div>
  <div class="square">Text</div>
  <div class="square">Text</div>
  <div class="square">Text</div>
  <div class="square">Text</div>
  <div class="square">Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
 var color = ["rgb(255, 0, 0)",
"rgb(255, 255, 0)",
"rgb(0, 255, 0)",
"rgb(0, 255, 255)",
"rgb(0, 0, 255)",
"rgb(255, 0, 255)"];

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("square");
            
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
   elements.item(i).style.backgroundColor = color[i];
```

```html
 <div id="container">
    <div class="square">A </div>
    <div class="square"> B</div>
    <div class="square"> C</div>
    <div class="square"> as</div>
    <div class="square"> asd</div>
    <div class="square">ad </div>
</div>
```